from ssh, powershell say the path doesn't exist, still execute my script
So I simply ssh (from unix) and (in windows) change path and execute a script. Note that the path is  'C:\Users\Public\docker_service\LayoutMlgit'.
    ssh user@192.168.0.47 "cd C:\\Users\\Public\\docker_service\\LayoutMlgit && powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File auto_launch.ps1"

    *cd : Impossible de trouver le chemin d'acces "C:\Users\Public\docker_service\LayoutML\layoutLMgit", car il n'existe 
    pas.*
    ***in english: can't find access path xxx cause it doesn't exist***
    + cd C:\Users\Public\docker_service\LayoutML\layoutLMgit

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Public...tML\layoutLMgit:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

it can't find that path;
but... in the end, it still executes my script from this same ssh command:

   time="2024-06-21T16:04:54+02:00" level=warning msg="C:\\Users\\Public\\docker_service\\LayoutMLgit\\docker-compose.yml: `version` is obsolete"
    Container layoutmlgit-test-1  Created
    Container layoutmlgit-tensorboard-1  Recreate
    Container layoutmlgit-api-1  Recreate
    Container layoutmlgit-tensorboard-1  Recreated
    Container layoutmlgit-api-1  Recreated
   Attaching to api-1, tensorboard-1, test-1
   test-1         | Fri Jun 21 14:04:55 2024       
   test-1         | +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   test-1         | | NVIDIA-SMI 535.98.01              Driver Version: 536.99       CUDA Version: 12.2     |
   test-1         | |-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
   test-1         | | GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |

How powershell can lies to me and still executes this script from the path that 'doesn't exist'? By the way, I have checked and there is only ONE script with this name and it is only on this specific path : C:\Users\Public\docker_service\LayoutMlgit'. But then:
+ cd C:\Users\Public\docker_service\LayoutML\layoutLMgit

I have never specified that. And I have no idea HOW powershell could 'invente' this path. Good news is that it still works. But I'm totally lost at this weird behavior.

PowerShell isn't necessarily lying to you - if the user account doesn't have access to read C:\Users\Public then it won't be able to find the leaf path

Presumably, the error messages comes from a different cd (Set-Location) command, namely one inside your auto_launch.ps1 script.
If the cd command shown were the problem, your script would never be invoked, given your use of && to conditionally chain the two commands.
Also, use of && (without getting a syntax error) implies that PowerShell (Core) 7 is the shell used in the ssh session.
Unless you expressly need to execute your script via powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI, you could just invoke auto_launch.ps1 directly, in-process (... && ./auto_launch.ps1)
